# ArrayIndexOutOfBound Error - Java

Tags: java

I am getting a weird error, I'm not sure why its there can anybody spot where the error is?

Error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -61
    at ca.serict.game.gfx.Screen.render(Screen.java:55)
    at ca.serict.game.entities.Player.render(Player.java:57)
    at ca.serict.game.level.Level.renderEntities(Level.java:67)
    at ca.serict.game.Game.render(Game.java:168)
    at ca.serict.game.Game.run(Game.java:127)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If you need to see code from any of those lines the errors are listed just let me know.

Screen.java Line 55:

```
int col = (colour >> (sheet.pixels[xSheet + ySheet * sheet.width + tileOffset] * 8)) & 255;
```

Player.java Line 57:

```
screen.render(xOffset,  + modifier, yOffset, (xTile + 1) + yTile * 32, colour);
```

Level.java Line 65 - 69:

```
public void renderEntities(Screen screen) {
    for (Entity e : entities) {
        e.render(screen);
    }
}
```

Game.java Line 168:

```
level.renderEntities(screen);
```

Game.java Line 157 - 128:

```
    if (shouldRender) {
        frames++;
        render();
    }
```

Screen 55's Public Void:

```
public void render(int xPos, int yPos, int tile, int colour, int mirrorDir) {
    xPos -= xOffset;
    yPos -= yOffset;

    boolean mirrorX = (mirrorDir & BIT_MIRROR_X) > 0;
    boolean mirrorY = (mirrorDir & BIT_MIRROR_Y) > 0;

    int xTile = tile % 32;
    int yTile = tile / 32;
    int tileOffset = (xTile << 3) + (yTile << 3) * sheet.width;
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        if (y + yPos < -0 || y + yPos >= height)
            continue;
        int ySheet = y;
        if (mirrorY)
            ySheet = 7 - y;
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            if (x + xPos < -0 || x + xPos >= width)
                continue;
            int xSheet = x;
            if (mirrorX)
                xSheet = 7 - x;
            int col = (colour >> (sheet.pixels[xSheet + ySheet * sheet.width + tileOffset] * 8)) & 255;
            if (col < 255)
                pixels[(x + xPos) + (y + yPos) * width] = col;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, please show all relevant code, especially the method that contains line 55 of Screen.java.

Comment: Well yes, we could do with knowing what `Screen.render` looks like, to start with. Clearly you're trying to access element -61 of some array or other, but without any code I don't see how we could possible tell you where the error is.

Comment: Lol. Yes, we would need to see the code somewhere. More specifically at the line that throws the error.

Comment: It looks like `xSheet + ySheet * sheet.width + tileOffset` evaluates to `-61`. It's hard to say why that would happen.

Comment: Now all we know is that `xSheet + ySheet * sheet.width + tileOffset` is -61.  You still haven't shown all relevant code.  How are those variables calculated?  What are their current values?

Comment: I updated with all the code I believe. Does that help more?

Comment: It doesn't help to show us the line of each point in the stack where the exception occurs. I suggest you construct an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), pay specific attention to the "self-contained" part.

Comment: @KevinHarrison: There are now *lots* of variables involved - have you looked at the values of them? In particular, `xSheet`, `ySheet`, `sheet.width` and `tileOffset`.

Comment: Any reason you're afraid to show us Screen:55??

Comment: Have you used a debugger? If you did, you'd already have fixed this.

Comment: Do note that an index like `[xSheet + ySheet * sheet.width + tileOffset]` can very easily generate an out-of-bounds (negative, in this case) index value.  You need to carefully examine the sources of that expression and also carefully consider whether you're calculating it correctly.  (This is your job, not ours.)

Comment: @Bmargulies I'm using Eclipse to code. Hot Licks, I did show screen 55. Ill update with the whole public void for Screen:55 by the way.

Comment: @HotLicks if you don't have anything constructive to say I ask that you please don't post at all :) I understand what an out-of-bounds error is, I just can't seem to locate the actual bug.

Comment: Note that it said "51" for a long time.  Thanks for *finally* fixing your error.

Comment: And it should be quite easy to locate the bug if you but put a breakpoint on line 55 and see what the values are.  Or, if you don't have a good debugger, insert println statements.  This is a simple bug you should not have needed any help for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are calculating your array index using this expression:

```
xSheet + ySheet * sheet.width + tileOffset
```

You need to make sure the value is inside the range of your array `sheet.pixels`. For that you can write a small method to clamp the index:

```
public int clamp(int index, int start, int end) {
    return index > end ? end : index < 0 ? 0 : index;
}
```

and use it like that:

```
 int i = clamp((xSheet+ySheet*sheet.width+tileOffset),  0, sheet.pixels.length-1)
 sheet.pixels[i];
```

This way you'll be sure to have index inside the range [0, sheet.pixels.length-1], But still you need to know if that is meaningful for your use case.

Comment: Error under sheet.pixels[i]

Comment: Except by very rare exception, doing this is not a good idea. It gets rid of the error but leaves you with usually unwanted behaviour.

Comment: @Dukeling, that's why I said OP needs to check whether it makes sense or not for his use case. Actually the calculation should give the right result, if it does't then there must be something wrong with.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally we would have the code from Screen:55. But it looks to me like you are access an element outside of the array. Try printing the size of the array you are accessing in Screen:55 and you should see the issue.

Comment: It's even more basic than that. The array index the OP is trying to access is *negative*.